# Eigen functor undeclared when building Tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to contribute to the Tensorflow code by adding non-inverse hyperbolic functions (sinh and cosh), as requested in [issue #7531]
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7531).

When I test the build with the command

```
$ bazel test --config opt //tensorflow/core/kernels:cwise_ops_test
```

But I get the error:

```
> ...
>  external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:1446:3:
> note: 'sinh' should be declared prior to the call site or in an
> associated namespace of one of its arguments T sinh(const T &x) {   ^
> 1 error generated. Target //tensorflow/core/kernels:cwise_ops_test
> failed to build Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of
> failed build steps. INFO: Elapsed time: 6.106s, Critical Path: 5.78s
> 
> Executed 0 out of 1 test: 1 fails to build.
```

The full output can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/uDzX3CH5).

What I did was add these two templates in `cwise_ops.h`:

```
template <typename T>
struct acos : base<T, Eigen::internal::scalar_acos_op<T> > {};

template <typename T>
struct atan : base<T, Eigen::internal::scalar_atan_op<T> > {};

// The following two templates are new:
template <typename T>
struct sinh : base<T, Eigen::internal::scalar_sinh_op<T> > {};

template <typename T>
struct cosh : base<T, Eigen::internal::scalar_cosh_op<T> > {};
```

and made two new files `cwise_op_sinh.cc` and  `cwise_op_cosh.cc`, which are just copies of the non-hyperbolic versions with references to sin or cos replaced with sinh and cosh, respectively. As far as I can see, the hyperbolic functions are now implemented exactly like the other math functions from the Eigen library. But as far as I can see the error it gives references to missing declarations in the Eigen source.

This is my very first open source contribution and on top of that I'm fairly new to C++. What I did wrong might be obvious with more C++ experience.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your `cwise_op_sinh.cc' and 'cwise_op_cosh.cc' into the corresponding BUILD file? Quick search tells me it should be [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d23960e29c3efb1b30c5cb6f8f3368635b97f29/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/BUILD) but I can be wrong. You definitely have to tell Bazel about your new files though.

Answer (score 0):

(*This should be a comment on OP's question but I lack the required karma.*)

The `--config opt` flag seems wrong, did you mean `-c opt` for optimized build? `--config opt` means use the "opt" configuration from the bazelrc file, which supposes you have lines in the bazelrc file like "build:opt --flag1=value1" and similar. If you don't, then Bazel should display a warning saying:

```
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: "opt"
```

or something to this effect.